# vuetify datepicker clear dates and re render component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a datepicker in vuetify js that im looking to clear the dates and refresh the component.

I have a v-data table that is filtered based on the dates range array, I want to be able to either add a v-btn clear in the datepicker to do this or have a clear X btn on the text field.

```
data(){
    return
    { 
      date:['',''],
      menu:false,
     }

   }


  <v-menu
    ref="menu"
    v-model="menu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    :return-value.sync="dates"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    min-width="290px"
  >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">

      <v-text-field
        v-if="selectedTask"
        label="Select Start Date Range"
        readonly
        v-on="on"
        v-model="dates"
      ></v-text-field>


    </template>

     <v-date-picker v-model="dates" range>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn text color="primary" @click="menu = false">Cancel</v-btn>
      <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.menu.save(dates)">OK</v-btn>
     </v-date-picker>


  </v-menu>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a clear button in the date picker like below

```
<v-date-picker v-model="dates" range>
  <v-btn 
    text color="primary" @click="menu = false">Cancel
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn 
    text color="primary" @click="$refs.menu.save(dates)">OK
  </v-btn>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <v-btn 
    text color="primary" @click="$refs.menu.save([])">Clear
  </v-btn>
</v-date-picker>
```

You can also make the text field `clearable` and it will append a clear icon

```
<v-text-field
  v-if="selectedTask"
  label="Select Start Date Range"
  readonly
  v-on="on"
  v-model="dates"
  clearable
>
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: thx anees, one last thing, i have my list rendered from a custom filter based on those dates. When i clear is there a way to re render my list, which would show ALL list items just like on initial load. Because right now your method will clear the text field but not re render my list base on the dates that were cleared aka dates =[' ',' '], this would show all my list items which is what i would like on clear.

Comment: Yes, you can emit an event when the date is being cleared. You and then catch the event from the component where their list is rendered. Please check the docs on how you can emit and catch it https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Hi @dontay did you find any solution for your first comment here?

Answer (score 4):

Needed to reset the whole component, including UI choices at datepicker which user has made. Did it by introducing `v-if="!isReset"` for `v-date-picker` and toggling `isReset` upon clearing event (which destroys and then creates the component, effectively resetting ui state).

Script - `onClear` method

```
  //* Resets data input component state
  onClear() {
    this.isReset = true
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.isReset = false
      //* Resetting your data to initial state, eg:
      this.$emit(this.emits.onSave, this.latestAcceptedValue)
    })
  }
```

Template - introduce `v-if` to toggle the  component

```
  <v-date-picker v-if="!isReset" v-model="dates" range>
      <v-btn text @click="onClear">Cancel</v-btn>
  </v-date-picker>
```

Comment: Resetting the UI element is the best for us so far. In our case, we have a TODAY button in the picker element (does what you expect) but the picker was not re-rendering back to the selected date.

Solution for us was to use your **v-if** binding but to add watch on the model attribute: `watch: { dates: function() { this.isReset = true; this.$nextTick(() => { this.isReset = false; }) } ...`

Heavy handed, but formerly only on the TODAY click event, needed it for other external changes to the model too. No downsides yet.